# C Assign enum values to members in structures?

Tags: c

I have 2 enumerations, color with 2 colors, and car type with 13 car types. I have a car structure, with 2 respective members. How can I assign an enumerated value through a loop if my structure is in an array?

```
enum carType {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M};
enum color {BLACK, WHITE};

typedef enum carType CarType;
typedef enum color Color;

struct car {                                 
CarType myCarType;
Color myColor;
};                  

typedef struct car Car;

void createGarage(Car *garage)
{ 



}

main()
{ 
Car garage[26];
createGarage(garage);
}
```

How can I loop through my array of garage, and ensure that each car type has both black and white colors?

I know I have 26 spaces in my garage array so I know I could use a for loop, but how would I exactly do the assignment?

Comment: `for(CarType type = A; type <= M; ++type) for(Color color = BLACK; color <= WHITE; color++) *garage++ =(Car){ type, color};`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add an extra element to each `enum` to hold the size, so you can loop over all the values.

```
enum carType {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, carType_size};
enum color {BLACK, WHITE, color_size};

void createGarage(Car *garage)
{ 
    for (int t = 0; t < carType_size; t++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < color_size; c++) {
            garage->carType = t;
            garage->color = c;
            garage++;
        }
    }   
}
```

This depends on the fact that `enum`s default to assigning values sequentially from `0`. This won't work if you have an `enum` where you override this with specific values, but that's an uncommon style.